# How do you delete the keyring and change the passphrase for any cosmos sdk blockchain?

Tags: key, blockchain, passphrase, cosmos-sdk, keyring

I spent some time trying to change the passphrase for stride cosmos sdk blockchain. Even after deleting all keys, I was always prompted to enter the old passphrase when i created a new key and it wasnt clear if the keyring was deleted or not. .

Same problem after created multiple keys under the same default keyring and deleting all of them. The chain will still prompt for the same old passphrase. Import, export and recover commands also did not work to resolve this

Answer (score 0):

I just spent a lot of time on this so i'm adding this here to help others. Anyone who wants to change their keyring passphrase and is having trouble even after deleting all keys and being stuck with the same passphrase, the solution is to go to the .chain folder eg: .stride folder and delete the keyhash file. I had noticed deleting all keys would say "no record on the keyring" when you do strided keys list, but will still not change the passphrase. Also, when i tried the recover flag , it was maintaining the same passphrase and requesting for mnemonic. Anyways, it was deleting the keyhash file in the .stride directory (not the keyring-file directory) that solved this. After this, a stride keys add will ask for a new passphrase which will now allow you to use an entirely new passphrase and not be stuck with the old one. Good luck!